# How to perform Outer product of 2 vectors in Metal shaders?

Tags: swift, shader, metal

So I'm developing a Neural Network to run in iOS on the GPU, so using matrix notation I need (in order to backpropagate the errors) be able to perform an outer product of 2 vectors.

```
// Outer product of vector A and Vector B
kernel void outerProduct(const device float *inVectorA [[ buffer(0) ]],
                         const device float *inVectorB [[ buffer(1) ]],
                         device float *outVector [[ buffer(2) ]],
                         uint id [[ thread_position_in_grid ]]) {
    
    outVector[id] = inVectorA[id] * inVectorB[***?***]; // How to find this position on the thread group (or grid)?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `thread_position_in_grid` incorrectly. If you are dispatching a 2D grid, it should be `uint2` or `ushort2`, otherwise it only gets the `x` coordinate. Refer to table 5.7 in [Metal Shading Language specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf).

I'm not sure which outer product are we talking about, but I think the output should be a matrix. If you are storing it linearly, then your code to calculate the `outVector` should look something like this:

```
kernel void outerProduct(const device float *inVectorA [[ buffer(0) ]],
                         const device float *inVectorB [[ buffer(1) ]],
                         uint2 gridSize [[ threads_per_grid ]],
                         device float *outVector [[ buffer(2) ]],
                         uint2 id [[ thread_position_in_grid ]]) {
    
    outVector[id.y * gridSize.x + id.x] = inVectorA[id.x] * inVectorB[id.y];
}
```

Also, if you are dispatching a grid exactly the size of `inVectorA`x`inVectorB`, you can use attribute `threads_per_grid` on a kernel argument to find out how big the grid is.

Alternatively, you can just pass the sizes of the vectors alongside the vectors themselves.

Comment: This is the Outer product I'm talking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product, it's a product of 2 vectors.

Comment: It's a matrix, so you either need to dispatch a 2D grid or you can use a single thread to go over all the values and put them into matrix, but with a 1D grid you'll have to run `N = m x n` 1D grid and figure out the actual `x, y` indices by dividing the `N` by something else, which doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 1):

I was surprised to learn that Metal doesn't have a 2D cross product (aka inner product), so here it is

```
float cross( float2 A, float2 B )
{
    float2 C = A.xy * B.yx;  // <- note B's swizzle
    return C.x - C.y;
}
```

So to answer you question:

```
float X = cross( inVectorA.read( id ), inVectorB.read( id ) );
outVector.write( X, id );
```